# SharePoint REST API with Fetch POST

Tags: rest, jquery

Trying to create list item:

```
let data = new FormData();
data.append("__metadata", JSON.stringify({ "type": itemType }));
data.append("Title", 'newItemTitle');

return fetch(_spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items", {
    method: "POST",
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    body: data,
    headers: { 
        "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()            
    }
}).then(
        response => response.json())
        .then( 
            (r: any) => r.d.results);
}
```

Got following error: **415 Unsupported Media Type**

In **Request Payload**:

> ------WebKitFormBoundaryFSelaakwmV2hvl6e
>       Content-Disposition: form-data; name="__metadata"
>
> {"type":"SP.Data.MyListItem"}
>       ------WebKitFormBoundaryFSelaakwmV2hvl6e
>       Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Title"
>
> newItemTitle
>       ------WebKitFormBoundaryFSelaakwmV2hvl6e--

---

---

---

Meanwhile JQuery ajax request works fine:  **201 Created**

```
var item1 = {
    "__metadata": { "type": itemType1 },
    "Title": 'newItemTitle'
};

$.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
    data: JSON.stringify(item1),
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
    },
    success: function (data) {
        var i = data;
    },
    error: function (data) {
        var i = data;
    }
});
```

**Request Payload**:

```
{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.Data.MyListItem"},"Title":"newItemTitle"}
```

Any ideas how Fetch could be used to create list item? I assume that Request Payload format has to be JQuery-like...

---

---

**Update:**

Thanks to [wjervis](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/20615/wjervis) here is working example:

```
var item = {
    'Title': 'newItemTitle'
};


return fetch(_spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items", {
    method: "POST",
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    body: JSON.stringify(item),
    headers: { 
        "Accept": "application/json; odata=nometadata",
        "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=nometadata",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()            
    }
})
```

Comment: Are you in SharePoint Online or On Premise? If On Prem, do you have SP1 installed?  If so, use [JSON Light](https://blogs.office.com/2014/08/13/json-light-support-rest-sharepoint-api-released/).  You specify `odata=nometadata`, and you simply post the data for the fields.  No need to specify the `__metadata` property.  Not sure if it works with `FormData` though.

Comment: Thanks for your responce! I use both Online and 2013SP1 editions. Updated initial question.

Comment: Just realized, you're missing the content-type header: `"content-type": "application/json; odata=nometadata"` (or verbose, if you prefer it).  It's in your ajax example, but not your fetch.

Comment: Yes, that was the case! Thanks a lot! I suggest you post an answer to the original question and I'll mark it as an 'answer', If you wish so, of course...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The content-type header is missing from your fetch request:

```
fetch(odataurl, {
    method: "POST",
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    body: JSON.stringify(body),
    headers: { 
        "Accept": "application/json; odata=nometadata", // or odata=verbose|minimalmetadata  (minimalmetadata is default if odata not specified)
        "Content-Type": "application/json; odata=nometadata", // or odata=verbose|minimalmetadata  (minimalmetadata is default if odata not specified)
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()            
    }
});
```